# Call Angular function in controller and pass result to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with Angular's digest cycle going crazy:

```
angular.js:12330 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

I have this custom Directive:

```
<b-bar-chart b-data="getData(question)"></b-bar-chart>
```

in Which, the getData function calls a function in the controller (NOT IN THE DIRECTIVE so using & instead of = in the directive for one way binding does not work). Controller function:

```
$scope.getData = function (question) {
    return [
      {
        'name': 'Strongly Agree',
        'value': question.stats.responsePercentages.stronglyagree
      },
      {
        'name': 'Agree',
        'value': question.stats.responsePercentages.agree
      }
    ]
  }
```

In the Directive I have this:

```
scope: {
    // I think this should this be = and not &, because the function is in the controller and not in the directive
    data: '=bData'
},
```

And in the directive template I have this:

```
<li ng-repeat="d in data">
    <div class="percent">{{d.value|number:0}}<span>%</span></div>
    <div class="fm-bar-text">{{d.name}}</div>
</li>
```

It looks like it continues to call the code in the controller which causes unnecessary loops. Is there a way to make sure the getData function is called only once, or is there a different solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`getData` should not return a new array, otherwise Angular assumes the data is new. You should assign the result to `$scope` and bind it that way. Its generally best to avoid function calls when binding.

Comment: In one instance where this is used, the directive is inside a loop (of `questions` so `question` is inside the loop) in this case, how would one bind the data to $scope as suggested? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: you could map the result to what you need ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing `getData(question)` every digest cycle, refactor to compute it only when `question` changes:

Parent Controller:

```
 $scope.$watch("question", function(newValue) {
     $scope.bData = $scope.getData(newValue);
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <!-- Re-factor this -->
 <b-bar-chart b-data="getData(question)"></b-bar-chart>

 <!-- TO this -->
 <b-bar-chart b-data="bData"></b-bar-chart>
```

So instead of computing the array every digest cycle, a new array is created only when the `question` changes.

Answer (score 0):

In directive `=` used for two way binding between scope variables. In your directive you are binding it to a function **return value** which will be considered as a new value every time and digest process will take place continuously.

I would suggest to call the function inside directive and assign it to a scope variable.

Check out **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrpruthvi/9aukxs2f/1/)**.

**Directive:**

```
MyApp.directive("bBarChart", function($compile){
    return {
      restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      data: '&bData'
    },
    template: '<li ng-repeat="d in data_values">' +
      '<div class="percent">{{d.value|number:0}}<span>%</span></div>' +
      '<div class="fm-bar-text">{{d.name}}</div>' +
        '</li>',
    link: function(s, e, a){
        s.data_values = s.data();
    }
  }
});
```